Perform RAG in JSON formatted data
I have json data look like this,
{
    {
        'id': 'p1',
        'category': 'category1',
        'description': 'description1'
    },
    {
        'id': 'p2',
        'category': 'category2',
        'description': 'description2'
    },
    {
        'id': 'p3',
        'category': 'category3',
        'description': 'description3'
    }
}

I want to perform similarity search in only in description and get the relevant top 5 'id's. Free to use any embedding technique. What is the best vector store and how to do this task?
I converted embedding into an NumPy array.

Welcome to StackOverflow, what have you tried so far? Please include your code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
